# R dollar values to number conversion, problems with commas, decimals, dollar signs, data types

Tags: r, regex, types

I have this data frame:

```
january_marketing_spend
```

And when I look at the structure I see these types:

```
str(january_marketing_spend)

'data.frame':   2088 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date        : chr  "2021-05-19" "2021-05-19" "2021-05-19" "2021-05-19" ...
 $ Source_Group: chr  "Pepperjam" "Adwords" "Organic - Fb" "Insta Ads" ...
 $ Spend       : chr  "$0.00" "$0.00" "$0.00" "$0.00" ...
```

Here are two images of the data frame. The first image shows some the higher Spend values. The second image shows some of the low Spend values.

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to clean up the Spend name with this code. I want to strip the $ and . and the commas.

```
january_marketing_spend$Spend = as.numeric(gsub("\\$", "",january_marketing_spend$Spend))
```

I noticed this code turns these high values (in the four-digits with commas) into smaller values, three digit values in the hundreds.

Is there an order of operations here that I need to understand? Should I first try to get rid of the comma, then the decimal, then remove the dollar sign, then turn to numeric? I'm trying combinations of things without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try amending the regex in your `gsub` call to something that replaces any non-numeric character:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]", "", c("$9,372.45", "$111.00", "$0.00"), perl = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
[1] 937245  11100      0
```

`[^\\d]` picks out characters in the class (`[]`) that are not (`^`) numeric digits (`d` escaped using `\\`). You need to use Perl-compatible regexps for this to work, so set `perl = TRUE`.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the answer. I do have an issue, though, and maybe this is because I asked the question badly.  for example: $28,064.96 turns into 2806496 but I guess I need 28064.96 with the decimal after all :/

Comment: You just need to add the decimal point to your class of characters that you want to keep: `as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d\\.]", "", c("$9,372.45", "$111.00", "$0.00"), perl = TRUE))`. Or alternatively, you could just divide the whole column by 100!

Comment: Hey I think I'm starting to understand a little better. But I'm seeing another issue - sorry 

What are these specific numbers doing? ("$9,372.45", "$111.00", "$0.00")

I tested it on another similar data frame with different dollar numbers in it and it doesn't work. Is that because this other data frame doesn't have this value specifically? "$9,372.45"

Comment: No I just chose those numbers randomly. When you say it doesn't work, is the function returning anything or is it throwing an error?